# event control "@" in systemverilog in uvm defined AFTER assignments

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand the UVM driver code defined in a "verificationguide.com" UVM env example : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5r89

In the mem_driver.sv file, in the drive() task, the following code can be found : 
    if(req.wr_en) begin // write operation
      `DRIV_IF.wr_en <= req.wr_en;`
DRIV_IF.wdata <= req.wdata;
      @(posedge vif.DRIVER.clk);
    end

How is the event control @(posedge vif.DRIVER.clk); line written AFTER the events being controlled? 
Help me understand the intent of the developer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there to make sure `wr_en` is held active for at least one clock cycle before the next requested transaction. Otherwise the next transaction would immediately set it back to 0.